# Correct way to write the Handler for AWS Lambda Serverless.yml

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const server = require('./Helpers/server');

const app = {};
/**
 * Initiating the Server.
 */
app.init = () => {
   server.init();
};
app.init();
module.exports = app;
```

I have this index.js file which initiates the server.

```
/**
 * dependencies:
 * @type {module:http}:
 */
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const config = require('./config');
const StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
const router = require('./../Helpers/routing');
const generator = require('./../Services/generator');
const validator = require('./../Helpers/validator');
const printer = require('./../Helpers/printer');
const constants = require('./constants');
const Cookies = require('cookies');
const server = {};
/**
 * Core Server logic for parsing and choosing the handlers.
 * @param req: the Request object.
 * @param res: The Response object.
 */
server.unifiedServer = function (req, res) {
   const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
   const pathName = parsedUrl.pathname;
   const path = pathName.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '');
   const firstRoute = path.split("/")[0];
   const secondPath = path.substr(path.indexOf("/") + 1);
   const method = req.method.toLowerCase();
   const queryString = parsedUrl.query;
   const decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8');
   const header = req.headers['content-type'];
   const cookie = new Cookies(req, res);
   const chosenHandler = router.getPath(firstRoute);
   let postData = "";
   let handlerData;
   if (header === 'application/octet-stream') {
      let data = [];
      req.on('data', d => {
         data.push(d);
      }).on('end', () => {
         const buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
         handlerData = {
            path: secondPath,
            method,
            queryString,
            data: buffer
         };
         execHandlers(handlerData);
      });
   } else {
      req.on('data', function (data) {
         postData += decoder.write(data);
      }).on('end', () => {
         postData += decoder.end();
         postData = generator.generateParsedJSON(postData);
         handlerData = {
            path: secondPath,
            method,
            queryString,
            postData
         };
         execHandlers(handlerData);
      });
   }

   /**
    * Method to send the response back to the client.
    * @param responseData: The response data to be send.
    * @param statusCode: The status code that to be send.
    * @param cookies: The array containing the cookies.
    */
   function sendResponse(responseData, statusCode, cookies) {
      responseData = validator.validateUndefined(responseData) ? responseData : {};
      statusCode = validator.validateNumber(statusCode) ? statusCode : 500;
      responseData = JSON.stringify(responseData);
      try {
         if (validator.validateUndefined(cookies)) {
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
               const oneCookie = cookies[i];
               printer.printHighlightedLog(oneCookie);
               cookie.set(oneCookie[constants.COOKIE_KEY], oneCookie[constants.COOKIE_VALUE]);
            }
         }
         res.setHeader(constants.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT, constants.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);
         res.writeHead(statusCode, constants.HEADERS);
         res.end(responseData);
         printer.printHighlightedLog("RETURNING: " + responseData + "FOR PATH: " + handlerData.path);
      } catch (e) {
         printer.printError(e);
      }
   }

   /**
    * Method to execute the Handlers.
    * @param handlerData: The request object after parsing it.
    */
   function execHandlers(handlerData) {
      if (handlerData.method === 'options') {
         sendResponse({}, 200);
      } else {
         let promise = chosenHandler(handlerData);
         promise.then((responseObject) => {
            sendResponse(responseObject[0], responseObject[1], responseObject[2]);
         }).catch(err => {
            sendResponse(err[0], err[1], err[2]);
         });
      }
   }
};
//TODO: Add the HTTPS Server.
/**
 * Method to create the Server.
 */
server.httpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   server.unifiedServer(req, res);
});
/**
 * Initializing the server.
 */
server.init = () => {
   /**
    * Method to listen on the port.
    */
   server.httpServer.listen(config.port, () => {
      console.log("Server Listening on Port ", config.port);
   });
};
/**
 * exporting the server module.
 */
module.exports = server;
```

This is my Server.js app.

```
#serverless.yml

service: serverless-nodejs-app

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev
  region: ap-south-1

functions:
  app:
    handler: index.app # reference the file and exported method
    events: # events trigger lambda functions
      - http: # this is an API Gateway HTTP event trigger
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors: true
      - http: # all routes get proxied to the Express router
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
```

This is my serverless.yml.

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'app'",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app'",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
        "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
    ]
}
```

This is the error Message.

I want to know what is the correct way of writing the handler for Serverless.yml. 
I do not want to use express. How can I invoke my index.js-> app.init() from serverless.yml? 
And what am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: whats the purpose of workers and server?

Comment: Server is the file where I have created the HTTPServer. 
Workers you can ignore for now.

Comment: why are you creating an http server

Comment: Because I am trying to create a HTTP server so that my API can listen for incoming requests.

Comment: why don't you do the usual way, define the end points in the serverless.yml , and one handler function per lambda

Comment: This is a legacy code. And I have this architecture. Can you help me to route requests to my index.js using the serverless.yml?

Comment: how many end points do you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203971/discussion-between-pronoy999-and-arun-k).

Comment: There are more than 2,000 endpoints.

Comment: are you going to create one lambda per end point

Comment: No. I want to move any request to my server.js which will automatically handle those requests.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, it uses `lambda-api` instead of express. the syntax looks similar to express. but i haven't used this. have a look at it.

```
# Functions
functions:
  serverless-api-sample:
    name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-serverless-api-sample
    handler: handler.router
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: 'v1/{proxy+}'
          method: any
```

## lambda code

```
const app = require('lambda-api')({ version: 'v1.0', base: 'v1' })
app.put('/posts/:post_id', (req,res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    params: req.params
  })
})
```

Reference:

https://www.jeremydaly.com/build-serverless-api-serverless-aws-lambda-lambda-api/
https://github.com/jeremydaly/lambda-api

Comment: What is the key "help" used for? And why it is index.handler?

Comment: sorry its my function name , let me rename

Comment: handler is `handler.ts` file.

Comment: have a look at this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html

Comment: i haven't done this, but this method will let us define one lambda to serve multiple end points

Comment: you dont want to use express? there is a serverless-express library, it will help us integrate serverless with express

Comment: Is there any way other than using Express?

Comment: Only method i can think of it is, you can define an endpoint in serverless for e.g `/pets` but you define the http method as `ANY`, it means , the same end point can serve ''GET (get a pet)", "POST (create a pet)", "PUT (update a pet)", "DELETE (delete a pet)" . Also one lambda handles all of the above requests.

Comment: But what if there are other end points other than ```/pets```

Comment: Ya i get it, other method is what you are trying to do proxying the request to one and only lambda. i think your method method will work well with serverless-express. it will also let you use middlewares and stuffs

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are trying to create a server inside a lambda using express which is wrong.
If you want to create serverless project,

1. Create a simple node project using

   `npm init`
2. Install serverless package
3. Generate serverless files using

   serverless create --template aws-nodejs
4. Install serverless-offline package
5. Add its referance in serverless.yml under plugins
6. create function inside serverless.yml as follows

   serverless create -f functionName

Your function is ready.
You can run project offline using command `serverless offline`
Now, you can hit URI mentioned under functions inside serverless.yml to test your lambda function.

Comment: No, you are wrong, I am trying to create a NodeJs server using AWS Lambda without using Express.